# what's the best way to detect if a word in NSString has a number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

example: word with number in string

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is an 101 **example1** string"]

Since **example1** has a number in the end and i want to remove it.  I can break it into an array and filter it out using predicate, but that seems slow to me since I need to do like a million of these.

What would be a more efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I think `([^0-9 ]+)\d+|\d+([^0-9 ]+)` should do it. Just replace it with `$1`.

Comment: ([^0-9 ]+)\\d+|\\d+([^0-9 ]+)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Chuck's response, here is the complete code in case someone might find it useful:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([^0-9 ]+)\\d+|\\d+([^0-9 ]+)"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str2
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [str2 length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$1"];
```